# writing a simple linux desktop environment in c++

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I would like to write a very simple Linux desktop environment or a program that runs without a DE, and here is my requirements

the application or DE will be a IPTV player (as a IPTV set-top boxes)
and I want it to run directly after booting (no login screen or such things)

1- the DE will be **full screen**

2- **no need to run any other GUI programs**, just command line programs called through my application, so no need to window manager nor display manager (if possible)

3-**minimal services**, just want to connect to LAN and read rtp (udp) streams

4-use **Qt and Qt Quick** to write this DE or application, and if couldn't use openGL

5-**MUST** use libvlc or any other library to read and play rtp streams

6-use **apt-get** to install or remove packages

7- keyboard and mouse support

I am a c++ and Qt programmer and I have a good Linux administration background

if you have any idea to help write the DE or if any existing one that run directly on XWindow, please help

the DE will be used as if the PC a a normal DVB receiver to list channels and select one to view

How could I boot my Qt application as a DE and put it in /usr/share/xsessions
as /usr/share/xsessions/myDE.desktop

**how to configure Qt to run without a window manager or display manager**

**should I use QApplication or any other class to run my app**

Comment: I want to know how to write this DE, how to boot linux to my application not gnome or any other DE

Comment: could I use Qt for this DE or Qt must run in a window manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to start by saying, you should think only about Qt 5 for, and forget about Qt 4. The Qt 4 design with QWS is a bit old, and hence flawed. Qt 5 has a nice QPA (Qt Platform Abstraction) interface for easily adding platform plugins which makes the architecture robust and flexible.

> how to configure Qt to run without a window manager or display manager

You can use Qt with the appropriate platform plugins, like eglfs, linuxfb, directfb, minimal, minimalegl, etc without complicated windows and display managers if you wanna have some lightweight solution.

Here you can find the list of the platform plugins that Qt 5 currently tries to support:

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/475cbed2446d0e3595e7b8ab71dcbc1ae5f59bcf:src/plugins/platforms

> should I use `QApplication` or any other class to run my app

No, you should use [QGuiApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qguiapplication.html) for this sort of thing. [QApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qapplication.html) is for widgets based application with Qt 5, and that is the major Qt version you should use for this.

That being sad, Qt Quick 2 rendering depends on the availability of the OpenGL api, so you need to have that in place for your information. That does not necessarily mean hardware acceleration with GPU. Having a software based implementation of the open standard is also fine.